# How to create a PDF to image shortcut in the Shortcuts app

Tags: macos, pdf, shortcuts-app

Specifically, I'd like to use Shortcuts.app to receive a PDF in Finder quick actions, create a new folder at the path of the PDF, and export the pages within the PDF as a user-defined image type.

I can't seem to understand how Shorcuts.app operates using folder variables. I understand it's easy to create a shortcut that exports PDF pages as images directly at the root of the PDF but I'd like to create a folder first.

Comment: Exactly what are you having trouble with in Shortcuts: creating an action to convert a PDF to an image file or creating a folder within a certain folder? Can you show us what you done so far and the error messages you have been getting, if any?